# Changing CRS of raster and vector data to either similar projected or geodetic crs

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

This is the output I get when I check the crs of raster and vector data. I want to extract raster data around buffer of district centroids calculated for all the polygons in vector data file. But since these two have different crs and that too in geodetic form I don't understand what should I do? whether I reproject them to same crs and that too in projected one instead of geodetic or to same geodetic crs.

Suggest something!!

```
> st_crs(cru_precip)
    Coordinate Reference System:
      User input: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 
      wkt:
    GEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]],
        CS[ellipsoidal,2],
            AXIS["longitude",east,
                ORDER[1],
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]],
            AXIS["latitude",north,
                ORDER[2],
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
                    ID["EPSG",9122]]]]
    > st_crs(districts)
    Coordinate Reference System:
      User input: WGS 84 
      wkt:
    GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        CS[ellipsoidal,2],
            AXIS["latitude",north,
                ORDER[1],
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
            AXIS["longitude",east,
                ORDER[2],
                ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Comment: You want to transform your 'districts' to the same CRS as 'cru_precip', `districts2 <- sf::st_transform(districts, crs = 9122)` should achieve this.

Comment: @Chris what about projected vs geodetic crs for centroid and buffer calculation?

Comment: Consider, once they are the same projection, centroid and buffer calculations will be correct. [cru raster](https://www.benjaminbell.co.uk/2018/01/getting-climate-data.html) example (3 parts), though I would suggest making the effort to do this with `terra` and `sf`.